# How do I sort <li> by <option> value?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-lists, selection

I'm trying to sort a ul by the value assigned by the option in the select tag.

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">

  <li>MCF3M0 - Functions and Applications</li>
  <select value="MCF3M0">
    <option value="1">1 Star</option>
    <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
    <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
    <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
    <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
  </select>
  <li>BDI3C0 - Entrepreneurship: The Venture</li>
  <select value="BDI3C0">
    <option value="1">1 Star</option>
    <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
    <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
    <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
    <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
  </select>
  <li>FSF3U0 - Core French</li>
  <select value="FSF3U0">
    <option value="1">1 Star</option>
    <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
    <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
    <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
    <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
  </select>
  <li>SPH3U0 - Physics</li>
  <select value="SPH3U0">
    <option value="1">1 Star</option>
    <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
    <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
    <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
    <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
  </select>
</ul>
<button type="submit">Submit Ratings</button>
```

I'm trying to sort these course by a user assigned rating. A javascript function that will help sort AND display a new list of the ranked courses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is invalid html

Comment: What are you trying to sort and by what?...

Comment: so take all the 1 stars and put them in a `select` and all the  2 stars and put them in a `select`..etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm trying to sort: MCF3M0 - Functions and Applications and the other 3 courses by a "rating"

Comment: Sounds like one selection box will target a div with another selection box inside of it.

Comment: but what is actually getting sorted?

Answer (score 0):

First: as you posted the HTML, it is not valid. A `<ul>` should have only `<li>` as direct children, not `<select>`. You should probably move the `<select>` inside the `<li>` tags.

If you want to have a javascript function change the order of these items when the dropdowns change values, you will want to attach an event handler (`onchange`) to each `<select>`, where the handler callback will collect the current value of each, then sort the corresponding `<li>` by those values. A library like jquery would do something like:

```
$('ul').on('change', 'select', function () { doSort(); });
```

From there, you just need to get `doSort` to sort the children of the list based on the values of the `<select>` inside the list items.